# How can I create a box/cuboid by entering values?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Warning: newbie question. I am just starting with Blender and learned about creating meshes and editing them. However, I miss something I did in 3DS Max about 15 years ago: I would like to create a box/cuboid just by entering the values and can't find a way to do this in a simple way.

So far I did it this way: added a box. Selected the vertices for one dimension (e.g. the ones of the face facing x into positive direction). Pressed g to translate, had to move it a bit and confirm by RMB. Entered the desired multiple of 1 for one dimension (e.g. x).  Then I had to repeat this for y and z, if necessary.

This hardly seems efficient. Did I miss something and can somewhere simply create a box e.g. with dimensions (4,1,9) in one step, as I know it from other software?

I hope I did not miss any existing question, but I did not find anything with my keywords. If I missed something please just close and hint me at the existing one. I might still be missing terminology for Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do it directly, but you can go to the properties menu (window on the right) and go to objects. Under scale you can change your dimensions very easily without selecting any vertices.

[image]

Comment: Was that what you needed ?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I didn't find this by searching for "edit box/cube by values", so maybe this question and your answer will help others, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to set the *dimensions* of your object, like in the screenshot. This way, you can even make use of blenders ability to use different units. After that, **apply** the scale of your object. This will normalise the scale while keeping vertices at the right position, and prevents many problems later on, especially if you plan to animate.

[image: apply scale of an object]

There is another way to achieve what you want: At the moment, you added the new object to your scene, there're some parameters to change - see screenshot. Sadly, this is only possible directly after creating the object. Blender creates objects and treats them as meshes directly after, while 3ds Max creates primitives, which can be edited with *edit poly* later. Both ways have their drawbacks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the Add <object> dialogue seems only to allow manipulation of location and rotation, not of the size/scale.

Comment: Well, yeah, Blender is kind of different in this case, because it does not know primitives - it just can create mesh objects in some primitive form. I missed this functionality of 3ds Max as well after my change to blender.